# Generate PNG`s from SVG`s (Asset Generator)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, svg, png

I am using Photoshop 2018 CC.
Currently I try to generate Apple iOS compliant icons from several SVG`s (https://materialdesignicons.com):

xx.png (24x24)
xx@2x.png (48x48)
xx@3x.png (72x72)

The problem is, the PNG`s are partly distorted or have sizes like 71x72.

My config:

[image]

Example SVG (https://materialdesignicons.com/icon/paperclip):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M16.5,6V17.5A4,4 0 0,1 12.5,21.5A4,4 0 0,1 8.5,17.5V5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 11,2.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,1 13.5,5V15.5A1,1 0 0,1 12.5,16.5A1,1 0 0,1 11.5,15.5V6H10V15.5A2.5,2.5 0 0,0 12.5,18A2.5,2.5 0 0,0 15,15.5V5A4,4 0 0,0 11,1A4,4 0 0,0 7,5V17.5A5.5,5.5 0 0,0 12.5,23A5.5,5.5 0 0,0 18,17.5V6H16.5Z" fill="#9b9c9c"/>
</svg>
```

All files are generated, but not in the correct size or distorted.